# Print stars according to the integers in an Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

In this exercise I had to write a method to print stars according to the integers of an array. I have finally got my code to pass, but I did not understand exactly why. The initial value of the integer star is 1, as 0 would not work properly. Why 1 and not 0? Can any of you give me the explanation?
Thank u loads!

```
public class Printer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // You can test the method here
        int[] array = {1,2,5,10};
        printArrayInStars(array);
    }

    public static void printArrayInStars(int[] array) {
        // Write some code in here
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            int number = array[index];

            for (int star = 1; star <= number; star++) {
                System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Work through the loop by hand

Comment: change `for (int star = 1; star <= number; star++) {` to `for (int star = 0; star < number; star++) {`. As to why it works, i would recommen dreading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: There is nothing to do with the initial value of star. You are running the loop from `1 to <= number`. If you want to use `star = 0` then you need to run the loop til l `< number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's normal. your loop should be something like :

```
for (int star = 0; star < number; star++)
```

or

```
for (int star = 1; star <= number; star++)
```